# Segmentation Fault: 11, Xcode 13.2. Issue on running

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

I am using Xcode 13.2 and facing this issue while trying to build. getting this error in many files.
[image: After running is finished, I get this error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked for me when I changed the optimization level of Swift compiler- Code generation.

[image: changed optimization level from - otpimize for speed to optimize for size]